# Convert Convex $ {L}_{1.5} $ Regression Problem into Semi Definite Program (SDP)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, regression, linear-regression, semidefinite-programming

Given the following Linear $ {L}_{1.5} $ Regression Problem:

$$ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{1.5} $$

How could one redefine it as [Semi Definite Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) Problem?

### My (Partial) Solution

Since $ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{1.5} = \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{1.5}^{1.5} $ one could write the problem as:

$$ \arg \min_{x} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {\left| {a}_{i}^{T} x - {b}_{i} \right|}^{1.5} $$

Now, what I tried doing is using auxiliary variables:

\begin{alignat*}{3} % Alignment is rl
 \text{minimize}  & \quad && {t}_{1} + {t}_{2} + \ldots + {t}_{n}  &     & \quad \\
 \text{subject to} & \quad && {s}_{i}^{1.5} \leq {t}_{i} &   & \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n \\
 & \quad && {a}_{i}^{T} x - {b}_{i} = {s}_{i} &   & \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n
 \end{alignat*}

And then form a Matrix using Schur.
Yet I can't make $ {a}_{i}^{T} x - {b}_{i} = \left| {s}_{i} \right| $.

**Update**
I managed to figure it out and find a tight boundary. See solution at the bottom.

Comment: Use $-s_i \leq a_i^Tx - b_i \leq s_i$ instead. It will be tight at optimality

Comment: @JohanLöfberg, Could you be specific in a full answer (Including the matrices) ? Thank You.

Comment: There is nothing more to be specific about, you have the solution there with that change

Comment: @JohanLöfberg, I'm not sure what you mean as I can't see how to form the matrix (Diagonals might require non negativity and your suggestion doesn't provide it). I thought what you wrote but I couldn't create the matrix. Thank You.

Comment: Which matrices are you talking about? Do you mean how to represent $s^{1.5}\leq t$ as a semidefinite constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should note that for any $ p \geq 1 $ the following holds $ \arg \min_{x} \left\| f \left( x \right) \right\|_{p} = \arg \min_{x} \left\| f \left( x \right) \right\|_{p}^{p} $. Which yields:

$$ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{1.5} = \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{1.5}^{1.5} = \arg \min_{x} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {\left| {a}_{i} x - b \right|}^{1.5} $$

Now, one could define a tight constraints in the form of:

\begin{alignat*}{3} % Alignment is rl
 \text{minimize}  & \quad && {t}_{1} + {t}_{2} + \ldots + {t}_{n}  &     & \quad \\
 \text{subject to} & \quad && {s}_{i}^{1.5} \leq {t}_{i} &   & \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n \\
 & \quad && -{s}_{i} \leq {a}_{i}^{T} x - {b}_{i} \leq {s}_{i} &   & \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n \\
 & \quad && {s}_{i} \geq 0 & & \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n
\end{alignat*}

The logic is straight forward, $ {s}_{i} $ will get as small as possible by the pressure of $ {t}_{i} $ until $ {a}_{i}^{T} x - {b}_{i} = {s}_{i} $ or $ {a}_{i}^{T} x - {b}_{i} = -{s}_{i} $ which is basically like enforcing $ \left| {a}_{i}^{T} x - {b}_{i} \right| = {s}_{i} $.

Using the appendix one could form it into SDP Form (Using $ u, v $ to from equalities from Inequalities):

\begin{alignat}{3} % Alignment is rl
 \text{minimize}  & \quad && \boldsymbol{1}^{T} t  &     & \quad \\
 \text{subject to} & \quad && {s}_{i} \begin{bmatrix}
 -1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} + {y}_{i} \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & -1 \\ 
 -1 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} + 1 \begin{bmatrix}
 0 &  0 \\ 
 0 & -1
 \end{bmatrix} \preceq 0 &   & \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n \\
      & \quad && {s}_{i} \begin{bmatrix}
      0 & -1 \\ 
      -1 & 0
      \end{bmatrix} + {y}_{i} \begin{bmatrix}
      -1 & 0 \\ 
      0 & 0
      \end{bmatrix} + {t}_{i} \begin{bmatrix}
      0 &  0 \\ 
      0 & -1
      \end{bmatrix} \preceq 0 &   & \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, n \\
      & \quad && A x + s - u = b & & \\
      & \quad && A x - s + v = b & & \\
      & \quad && -u, -v \preceq 0 & &
\end{alignat}

#### Appendix

$$ {s}^{\frac{3}{2}} \leq t, s \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \exists y : \begin{bmatrix}
 y & s \\ 
 s & t 
 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \begin{bmatrix}
 s & y \\ 
 y & 1 
 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 $$

This is easy to show remembering that a Symmetric Matrix $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}, \; A = \begin{bmatrix}
 a &  b \\ 
 b & c
\end{bmatrix} $ is PSD **if and only if** all elements on its diagonal are positive, $ a, c \geq 0 $ and $ a c \geq {b}^{2} $.